# why Rails 4 keeping memory usage up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, memory-management

I have a code which fetchng 1 50, 000+ records:

```
meter_data = MeterData.find_by_sql("SELECT tenant, meter_id, SUM(van) as van, SUM(vbn) as vbn,
                                       SUM(vcn) as vcn, SUM(ia) as ia, SUM(ib) as ib, SUM(ic) as ic,
                                       SUM(w3pht) as w3pht, SUM(pf3pht) as pf3pht, SUM(f) as f,
                                       SUM(whrec) as whrec, SUM(whtot) as whtot, SUM(varhrec) as varhrec,
                                       SUM(varhtot) as varhtot, SUM(whintvlrec) as whintvlrec,
                                       SUM(whintvldel) as whintvldel, SUM(w__phavg) as w__phavg,
                                       SUM(var__3phavg) as var__3phavg, SUM(w_3phavg) as w_3phavg,
                                       SUM(var_3phavg) as var_3phavg, SUM(phai) as phai, SUM(phbi) as phbi,
                                       SUM(phci) as phci, SUM(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd,
                                       MAX(w__3phmaxavgdmd) as w__3phmaxavgdmd_max, SUM(var__3phmaxavgdmd) as var__3phmaxavgdmd,
                                       SUM(w_3phmaxavgdmd) as w_3phmaxavgdmd, SUM(var_3phmaxavgdmd) as var_3phmaxavgdmd,
                                       date_time FROM `meter_data` WHERE (`date_time_i` >= #{@from_date} AND `date_time_i` <= #{@to_date}
                                       AND building = '#{@building_info}') GROUP by tenant, meter_id, date_time
                                       ORDER BY `meter_data`.`date_time_i` ASC")



raise 0
```

This usage about 750 MB and last I just raise with zero.

Problem is why not rails releasing memory?

Rails keeping memory usage 750 MB until I do ctrl+C.

Comment: i save 50%+ memory without using ORM now code using 250 MB !!
but still Rails keep memory usage 250 MB.. it should free when process done.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is Ruby and Ruby(MRI) is an interpreter with a garbage collector(GC). The GC will manage memory automatically for you. There are commands to invoke the GC explicitly but if you require this level of memory management you might also explore some other languages that support this behavior up front.

Comment: this issue seems with Rails Only.. i tested with pure Ruby code .. which worked fine and free memory after process done .